# how can I understand where this "submit" button/actionlink leads in ASP MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.NET MVC 4 and learning my way around an existing MVC 4 code base. I am trying to find the code that processes the the form corresponding to this submit button. I understand that the action link probably says how to process the "submit" button -- but I don't see any constructors that take three strings for an actionlink in the [microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

I am confused because there is no action field in the input tag.

How do I find out what happens once the person hits submit?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "disableSubmit" }))
{
...
<div class="buttons">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" /> | @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Admin")
</div>
}
```

**Update** When I go to "view source" to see the raw HTML I see

```
<form action="/Lab/Upload" ...
```

So that means it goes to the lab/upload controller?

The Javascript for the disable submit looks like this:

```
// Disable submit button after click
$(function () {
    $('.disableSubmit').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Submit button will submit the corresponding form. Action link has no dependency on it.

Comment: The `ActionLink` is pretty clear: `Admin` controller, `Index` action

Comment: what does "back to list" mean?

Comment: Back to list is just a link back to the index page, which is usually a list of items.  It's a way for the user to go back to the previous page(assuming they came from the list page) instead of submitting the form.

Comment: ActionLinks are not (typically) used to submit forms, they just generate a link which when clicked by the user goes to another page.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the submit button performs a regular form submit, then it will be inside of a `<form>` tag or `@Html.BeginForm` using block.

BeginForm will submit the form to the action that matches the name of the view, unless there is a parameter being passed that specifies the action name and/or controller name.

IF it is a form tag, then the `action="something"` attribute of the form tag will indicate the URL being submitted to, which is usually controllerName/ActionName` but could be different depending on what routing is setup.

The ActionLink you see is not related to the form or the submit, it is a regular link which is in effect a way for the user to go back to the previous page **instead** of submitting the form.

There is also the possibility that there is javascript attached to the submit button.  That's harder to find unfortunately due to the many ways that javascript can be wired up to a button.

Edit: Based on your update, I would strongly suspect there's javascript that supports this form.  I imagine the submit button is disabled until you meet some conditions that allow it to be displayed.  Maybe permissions, maybe filling the form out completely, it's hard to say.   Search the javascript for `disableSubmit`, as I suspect somewhere there is code that removes that class under certain conditions.

Edit 2: What is happening there is it disables the submit button after the first click so that you can't accidentally submit the for twice and cause problems with a duplicate submit(if this is Create form it avoids duplicate records).  As far as I can tell there should be an action of the same name as the *.cshtml file that it submits to.  Possibly with a [Post] or [HttpPost] attribute on the action.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the submit buttons in inside a **form** tag. If yes, what is the **action** attribute value of that ? That is the place the form will be submitted to.

You may see an HTML helper method called `Html.Beginform` in the view. This method render a form tag. You can go to the page and check the ***view source*** of the page to see what is the form tag looks like and what is the `action` method attribute value.

Ususally your controller will have an action method marked with `HttpPost` attribute to handle the form submit. Lets say your mark up is like this

```
<form action="User/EditUser">
   <input type="text" name=Name" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Now in your `UserController`, there may be an action method like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditUser(SomeModelIfExist model)
{
  // TO DO : save and redirect
}
```

the `Html.ActionLink` helper method renders an anchor tag. It has nothing to do with the form submit. So your action link helper will return the below markup

```
<a href="Admin/Index">Back</a>
```